# How to turn ON/OFF screen monitor using shell script and 'xrandr' linux command?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to turn on and off screen monitor in Ubuntu14.04 using key bindings.
I tried the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
output=$(xrandr | grep ' connected ' | awk '{print $1}' | head -1)
screenSize=$(xrandr | awk 'BEGIN {foundOutput=0}
/ '$output' / {foundOutput=1}
/\*\+/ {print $1}
/^[^ ]/ {if(foundOutput) exit 0}')
if [ "$screenSize" != "" ]; then
   xrandr --output $output --fb $screenSize --off
   espeak "Monitor off"
else
   xrandr --output $output --auto
   espeak "Monitor on"
fi
```

1) This above script is working fine in Ubuntu 10.04, but not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04.

2) I bind this script on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> key.

3) When I press this key binding it will off the monitor but again I pressed this key binding it will not start screen monitor.

4) I try to run this command

```
xrandr --output $output --auto
```

or

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --auto
```

but nothing happens.

5) I also tried this command

```
xset dpms force off
```

but if any key is pressed it will start the screen monitor.

So what should I do to turn the screen monitor on or off using a shell script?

Comment: Hi I was tested this script on laptop, so I got 1 thing is that if we run this script on desktop its working fine but if we are run this on laptop then it will turn off the screen but didn't start again.

Comment: Better suited for AskUbuntu I'd say.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I'm unsure, there is a script involved, so that qualifies as programming for me

Comment: @martin I'm not saying this should be closed; just suggesting that this might be more relevant and attract better answers on AskUbuntu. There's a script, but there's no difficulty with the script — it's mostly about available tools.

Comment: Do you want to completely turn it off, or dimming to zero brightness would be enough for you? I have script for my laptop when external monitor is connected - it dims the monitor and when its not connected - it dims the built-in screen. Let me know if you want something like this.

Comment: Please try this: xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --primary

Comment: As an aside, the `grep` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).  Try `xrandr | awk '/ connected/{print $1; exit(0)}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times a laptop will have it's own screen key binding that turns on and off the display. If your laptop has no such key, try searching for programs other than `xrandr` that will do what you want.
 Ubuntu's default screensaver can assign a key that will automatically turn off and lock the screen.

1. Navigate System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > System.
2. Click the `+`, name your custom shortcut anything you want, and put as the command `gnome-screensaver-command -la`.
3. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, then assign the shortcut you want to add.

These instructions can also be found here (with pictures): [askubuntu.com/questions/446601/how-can-i-lock-and-blank-the-screen-from-the-keyboard-in-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446601/how-can-i-lock-and-blank-the-screen-from-the-keyboard-in-14-04) You might even be able to get `xrandr` to work with the settings manager, but I don't know.